# LotusScript Create table in RichTextItem

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I'm new with Notes and LotusScript and I got a problem.

I need to create a table in a rich text item, I have used an "action partagée" (maybe "shared action" in English). My code runs without returning an error but my table is not visible.

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
    On Error Goto errorhandler

    Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace    
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim uidoc As Notesuidocument
    Dim doc_bdl As NotesDocument    
    Dim table As NotesRichTextItem
    Dim rtnav As NotesRichTextNavigator

    ' création du document
    Set uidoc = workspace.ComposeDocument("","","EXPEDITION")
    Set doc_bdl = uidoc.Document
    Set table = New NotesRichTextItem(doc_bdl,"rtTableau")

    ' création du tableau
    Call table.AppendTable(4, 3)
    Set rtnav = table.CreateNavigator
    Call rtnav.FindFirstElement(RTELEM_TYPE_TABLECELL)
    Dim iRow As Integer
    Dim iColumn As Integer
    For iRow = 1 To 4 Step 1
        For iColumn = 1 To 3 Step 1
            Call table.BeginInsert(rtnav)
            Call table.AppendText("Ligne " & iRow & ", Colonne " & iColumn)
            Call table.EndInsert
            Call rtnav.FindNextElement(RTELEM_TYPE_TABLECELL)
        Next
    Next

    Exit Sub

errorHandler:
    Print Lsi_info(2) & " : " & Err & " (" & Error & ") ligne " & Erl 

    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

I have read that to see the content of rich text items it's necessary to refresh the document. So I used examples in the help.
I tried to add this :

```
Call doc_bdl.Save(True, False)
Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
Call ws.ViewRefresh
```

I got no error but I still not see my table.

I tried this :

```
Call doc_bdl.Save(True, False)
Call doc_bdl.Refresh(True)
```

I got this error : "Illegal use of PROPERTY"

Can someone help me ? Thank you in advance

PS : English is not my language so please excuse my possible errors, I don't find french forums for help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this:

```
' Save your backend document with the updated RichText field
Call doc_bdl.Save(True, False)
' Open saved backend document as a uidoc
ws.EditDocument(True, doc_bdl)
```

If you want to build a table with content, and you don't know how many rows there will be (and/or if you want more control ov the formatting of the table) you can use this technique:

http://blog.texasswede.com/dynamic-tables-in-classic-notes/

Comment: Thank you. I try your solution but I still not see my table and now I have the default form that opens. I will see your link trying to understand it.